# I have a table with a currency column and an array of currencies, I want to assign each instance of the column with each element of the array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, for-loop

So that each elements of the array gets assigned to each instance of the column chronologically

This is what I've tried:

```
currencies = [...]

i = 0
Country.all.each do |country|
  Country.update(currency: currencies[i])
  i = i + 1
end

currencies.each do |currency|
  Country.all.each do |country|
    country.update(currency: currency)
  end
end
```

My expectation/desire is to get the first country column assigned with the value of the first array element, the second country column with the second element etc.

Comment: What happened when you tried the second code example? What was the result vs what did you expect. You question is very thin and lacking in information.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
i = 0
Country.all.each do |country|
  country.update(currency: currencies[i])
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler:

```rb
Country.all.each_with_index do |country, i|
  country.update(currency: currencies[i])
end
```

Any chance to use `zip` method:

```
Country.all.zip(currencies) do |country, currency|
  country.update(currency: currency)
end
```

Make it repeat:

```
Country.all.zip([:usd, :eur, :gbp].cycle) do |country, currency|
  country.update(currency: currency)
end
```